# Integrating product of a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate a function which involves vector multiplication. However I keep getting an error.

Assume *alphas* is some vector.
and consider the following bit of code:

```
g = @(x)prod(x.*alphas);
integral(g,-10,10);
```

This yields the following error:

> Error using  .*
>
> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in @(x)prod(x.*alphas)

Now, for a naive point of view. *g* is a scalar function. If *x* is some number then *g(x)* is a number as well.

I'm quite new to Matlab, and I cant quite understand the problem.
Any help would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `alphas` is a vector, it should have a value for every `x`. When you give `integral()` a function to integrate, it tries to evaluate the function `g` as `g(-10:0.1:10)` for example. If there are not the same amount of alphas, as `x`, then that error will be thrown.

The problem with using `integral()` here is, that you don't control the amount of `x` given to `g` inside `integral`, thus, you can not define `g` the way you did if you want to integrate.

**EDIT:** The following will do the job! thanks @Andras Deak

```
integral(g,-10,10,'arrayvalued',true);
```

Comment: Thanks! what would be the correct way to define *g* then?

Comment: @Cain What do you want to do? What kind of function you have that has different alphas? Can you post another question explaning what you want to do?

Comment: @Cain How about this? `g = @(x)prod(x(:)*alphas,2); integral(g,-10,10,'arrayvalued',true)`? Note that it seems that `'arrayvalued'==true` will stop the vectorized evaluation, so you can just use `prod(x*alphas)`.

Comment: Cool:) I suggest that Ander add it to his answer; I wouldn't have bothered to look into the details if it wasn't for his explanation of the problem.